# Fixed Button in Accordion

Tags: javascript, accordion

I have this html template. And I can't make the `.faq-nav` slide with the `.panel-body` or the `.panel-default`. Only from the each panel beginning to it's end.

http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/3778/

I thought it would be better just to leave the fiddle here.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, I did using css only.
http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/3780/

```
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle::before, #accordion a[data-toggle="collapse"]::before  {
    content:"\e113";
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    margin-right :1em;
}
#accordion .panel-title > a.accordion-toggle.collapsed::before, #accordion a.collapsed[data-toggle="collapse"]::before  {
    content:"\e114";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not why I'm asking for help xD

Comment: @Alien18 what is that you are looking for?

Comment: I'm trying to make the .faq-nav scroll with the .panel-body. Only from the panel beggining to it's end.

Comment: @Alien18 Onclick of top & close what should happen?

Comment: the top button should scroll top the top of the .panel-body and the close button should close the panel. But that part I already know how to do. I just don't know how to keep the buttons div fixed in the just the .panel-body.

Comment: @Alien18 Since, you have already done .faq-nav position:absolute; It will come in center as bottom:50%; You could alternatively do position:fixed; For it to remain fixed throughout.